# iOS Firebase sync not working after login token expires

Tags: ios, firebase

Firebase iOS version: 2.4.1.1

After having logged in the upstream synchronisation from the mobile to firebase stops after the login token expires. However downstream sync is still working.

This is not what I expected since I don't require the user to be logged in in order to write to Firebase.

This is usually not apparent, but it became clear when I experimented with very short Session lengths. In my testing I used 24 seconds, set through the admin interface.

Do I have strange expectations of the default behaviour or did i configure something by accident?

Firebase rules

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
}
```

In my AppDelegate

```
override init() {

    super.init()
    Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true
    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com");
    ref.authUser("xxx@gmail.com", password: "1234") {
        error, authData in
        if error != nil {
            // an error occured while attempting login
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("login sucessfully experiy date \(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: authData.expires.doubleValue))")
        }
    }

    ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock({ authData in
        if authData != nil {
            // user authenticated
            print("AuthEvent \(authData)")
        } else {
            // No user is signed in
            print("AuthEvent: user is signed out")
        }
    })
}
```

I have the following upload code (example)

```
func createSubscription(subscription: Subscription) {
    let commentRef = fireSubs.childByAutoId()
    commentRef.setValue(subscription.fireDict())
}
```

downstream (example)

```
fireSubs.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    self.subscriptions.insert(Subscription(snapshot: snapshot), atIndex: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is linked to the offline capabilities being enabled:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html

> If our app uses Firebase Authentication, the client will persist the
>   user's authentication token across restarts. If the auth token expires
>   while our app is offline, the client will pause our write operations
>   until we re-authenticate, else our writes might fail due to security
>   rules

So the app does to some degree indeed follow the documented behavior. One thing is that pausing the writes does not only happen when offline, but also when online and the token has expired.

Turing off disk persistence and the writes are not paused.

Comment: Yeah, this is indeed the expected behavior albeit potentially surprising / confusing.  Sorry.  :-(  We wanted to make sure we didn't accidentally lose all of your writes after you do a bunch of work while offline and then come online and your token is expired.  And so we pause your writes if your token expires and wait for you to re-auth with a valid token or unauthenticate.  Else your writes would be sent un-authenticated and might potentially fail.

For your use case, maybe you can just explicitly unauthenticate if your writes don't need auth?